Agregar a un objeto valores de otro objeto
tengo problema al querer combinar dos objetos, obtengo los valores de dos consultas distintas de las cuales genero dos objetos, lo que quiero es poder combinarlos para que solo sea un objeto, ya que tratan del mismo tema.


 //SONSULTA PARA OBTENER DATOS DEL UNIVERSO.
    $stid3 = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT A.CT, A.BBSUC, A.DISTANCIA BBDIST, B.NOM_SUCURSAL BNOM, C.*,
        FROM TABLA A, TABLA B, TABLA C, TABLA D 
        WHERE C.CT =  '$busqueda' AND A.CT = C.CT AND C.CT = D.CT(+)
        AND A.BBSUC = B.CVE_SUC");
    oci_execute($stid3);

    $search3 = array();
    while(($row3 = oci_fetch_object($stid3)) != false){
        $search3 = $row3;
    }

    foreach ($search3 as $key => $val) {
       
        if($val=="" || $val== "NINGUNO NINGUNO" || $val== "undefined"){
            $search3->$key  = '<i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" title = "Sin dato"></i>';
        }
        
    }
/*********************************************************************TABLA INFORMACION DE SELECCION******************************************************/
    $stid4 = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT A.CT, A.BBSUC, A.DISTANCIA BBDIST, B.NOM_SUCURSAL BNOM, C.*,
        FROM TABLA A, TABLA B, TABLA C, TABLA D 
        WHERE C.CT =  '$busqueda' AND A.CT = C.CT AND C.CT = D.CT(+)
        AND A.BBSUC = B.CVE_SUC");
        oci_execute($stid4);
    $search4 = array();
    while(($row4 = oci_fetch_object($stid4)) != false){
        $search4 = $row4;
    }

    foreach ($search4 as $key => $val) {
       
        if($val=="" || $val== "NINGUNO NINGUNO" || $val== "undefined"){
            $search4->$key  = '<i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" title = "Sin dato"></i>';
        }
        
    }
/**************************************************************************************/        
        //intento1
        $test = array_merge($search3,$search4);
        //intento2
        $test = array_push($search3,$search4);
        //intento3
        $search3->$search4;

        $infoComplete = array($search,$search2,$test );
        echo json_encode($infoComplete, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);



Obtengo los objetos por separado asi:
{"CAT": "SI", "UNIVERSO": "SI", "TC": "1", "PARTICIPA": "NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD"}

{"G_DES": "PRIORITARIA ", "DES": "1105- MARGINACIÓN"}

Quiero obtener algo asi:
{"CAT": "SI", "UNIVERSO": "SI", "TC": "1", "PARTICIPA": "NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD", "G_DES": "PRIORITARIA ", "DES": "1105- MARGINACIÓN"}


hola, creo que estas trabajando con json pero no me queda claro por que la sintaxis de json es "CAT":"SI y no CAT: "SI como muestras los ejemplo... puedes confirmar esto por favor ... antes de darte una respuesta...

No comprendo bien, es la respuesta que obtengo en el navegador, ambas tanto la Key como el Valor están entrecomilladas {"CAT": "SI", "UNIVERSO": "SI",...}

en tu ejemplo CAT no esta entre comillas ...

Si, es que el navegador en vista previa así me lo entrego, pero en la respuesta ambas están con comillas.

En teoria deberias implementar array_merge(array ...$arrays): array:
Aqui un breve ejemplo practico de la implementacion enconjunto con el uso de json_decode y json_encode:
<?php
// Objetos obtenidos de las consultas
$objeto1 = (object) array(
    'CAT' => 'SI',
    'UNIVERSO' => 'SI',
    'TC' => '1',
    'PARTICIPA' => 'NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD'
);

$objeto2 = (object) array(
    'G_DES' => 'PRIORITARIA',
    'DES' => '1105- MARGINACIÓN'
);

//escape de simbolos, conversion de objeto a json y luego al array.

$array1=json_decode(json_encode($objeto1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), true);
$array2=json_decode(json_encode($objeto2,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), true);


//Verificacion visual de estructuras individuales:

var_export([$array1,$array2]);

//solucion:

$ArrayCombinado =  array_merge($array1, $array2);
$ObjetoCombinado = (object) $ArrayCombinado;

//Verificacion visual de estructuras Combinado:

var_export(["Array_Combinado"=>$ArrayCombinado,"Objeto_Combinado"=>$ObjetoCombinado,"string_Json"=>json_encode($ObjetoCombinado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)]);


Output:
array (
  0 => array (
    'CAT' => 'SI',
    'UNIVERSO' => 'SI',
    'TC' => '1',
    'PARTICIPA' => 'NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD',
  ),
  1 => array (
    'G_DES' => 'PRIORITARIA',
    'DES' => '1105- MARGINACIÓN',
  ),
)

array (
  'Array_Combinado' => array (
    'CAT' => 'SI',
    'UNIVERSO' => 'SI',
    'TC' => '1',
    'PARTICIPA' => 'NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD',
    'G_DES' => 'PRIORITARIA',
    'DES' => '1105- MARGINACIÓN',
  ),
  'Objeto_Combinado' => (object) array(
     'CAT' => 'SI',
     'UNIVERSO' => 'SI',
     'TC' => '1',
     'PARTICIPA' => 'NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD',
     'G_DES' => 'PRIORITARIA',
     'DES' => '1105- MARGINACIÓN',
  ),
  // esto es lo que buscas...
  'string_Json' => '{"CAT":"SI","UNIVERSO":"SI","TC":"1","PARTICIPA":"NUEVA Y CONTINUIDAD","G_DES":"PRIORITARIA","DES":"1105- MARGINACIÓN"}', 
)

Al final la variable usable seria $ObjetoCombinado.
ejemplo:
echo $ObjetoCombinado->DES;

output:
1105- MARGINACIÓN


Lo implemento y te comento como fue, muchas gracias.

no necesita susar todo el codigo... solo la parte que necesitas para llegar a $ObjetoCombinado = (object) $ArrayCombinado;

al final si haces esto: echo $ObjetoCombinado->DES; el output debe ser 1105- MARGINACIÓN

Ok, en eso estoy.

Hermano muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me costo un poco entenderlo pero si lo logre, esto lo realizo con la finalidad de evitar trabajar con dos objetos de respuesta y no había encontrado una respuesta tan completa como la tuya, de nuevo gracias.

tambien podrias ejecutar las dos queries y obtener un solo resultado... pero eso ya es intermedio de base de datos ... y aqui estamos viendo lago de nivel basico...

Si lo pensé, ya que los datos pueden obtenerse también en una sola, pero pertenece a otra área y trabajo con lo que hay :).

Exacto eso mismo pense tambien ...
